# myTextField.text does not return any value

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield

I'm trying to make a numberline with boxes pointing at different values. Inside each box is a TextField where the user is supposed to wright down the value the box is pointing at. When all the boxes are filled out, the answere in the boxes should be compared to the correct answeres.

The problem is that when I try to acsess the text in the textField, 1-2 of them randomly won't return any values. The TextFields that don't respond are also impossible to edit and navigate inside after a number is filled out.

This is the code where I construct the textField:

```
var textFields:Array = [];
var box:Sprite = new Sprite();
var tfor:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
for (var i:int = 0; i<3; i++)
{
    tfor.size = 30;
    var tfb:TextField = new TextField();
    tfb.defaultTextFormat = tfor;
    tfb.width = boxWidth;
    tfb.height = boxWidth;
    tfb.maxChars = 3;
    tfb.text = "";
    tfb.restrict = "0-9.";
    tfb.multiline = false;
    tfb.x = bx;
    tfb.y = by;
    tfb.selectable = true;
    tfb.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
    box.addChild(tfb);
    textFields.push(tfb);
}
```

And this is where I check the answere:

```
public function checkBoxAnswere(numbs:Array) {
    var points:Number = 0;
    for(var i:int = 0; i<textFields.length; i++) {

        trace("numb:"+numbs[i]+"arrowText  "+textFields[i].text+"  .");

//begDes is a function whitch round a value mutch like the .toFixed(number) but returns a number insted of a string
        if(begDes(numbs[i], 2)==begDes(Number(textFields[i].text), 2)) {
           points+= 0.5;
         }

    }
    return points;
}
```

It is the textField.text that wont be read. There is no error massenges.

Comment: What is your trace output?

Comment: numb:2.7arrowText    .
numb:0.9arrowText  0.9  .
numb:1.5arrowText    .

Comment: when do you call "checkBoxAnswere"? What do you see in all TextFields when you run "checkBoxAnswere"

Comment: "checkBoxAnswere"  is placed inside  if(k.keyCode == 13) that is placed inside a function called by a KeyboardEvent. The TextFields apperte normal but when I click on them the wrighting-cursor is blinking at the left side of the text and the text is impossible to edit.

Comment: i can suppose you miss the text fields order: so some fields are empty, some of them are filled and in checkBoxAnswere you check them in different order they are displayed. try, for example, apply unique name to every tfb and make traces of text both in "onKeyboardEventHandler" (tracing target input text) and in "checkBoxAnswere"